# How can I retrieve array of db results and make all possible combination of pairs?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, combinations

can someone help me please:

This is the code:

```
 <?php
 //...db connection code ...

 function icecream($flavs, $size, $combinations = array()) {
    if (empty($combinations))
    {
       $combinations = $flavs;
    }

    if ($size == 1)
    {
       return $combinations;
    }

    $new_combinations = array();

    foreach ($combinations as $combination)
    {
       foreach ($flavs as $flav)
       {
          $new_combinations[] = $combination .' - '. $flav;
       }
    }

    return icecream($flavs, $size - 1, $new_combinations);
 }

 $sql = ("SELECT name FROM eissorten");
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $ice_all[] = $row['name'];
 }
 $ice_all = implode(', ',$ice_all);

 $flavs = array('Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Stracciatella');
 $output = icecream($flavs, 2);

 foreach($output as $outputs)
 {
    echo $outputs.'<br>';
 }

 ?>
```

It is giving me all possible flavour combinations with:

```
 $flavs = array('Vanilla', 'Strawberry', 'Chocolate', 'Stracciatella');
```

But I need to populate the array with $row['name'] from database, so when I do:

```
 $flavs = array($ice_all);
```

then it gives me the complete string of flavours.
What do I do wrong?

Comment: remove this line: `$ice_all = implode(', ',$ice_all);` and see if it works.

Comment: Doesnt work. I then get: 'Array to string conversion...' and it is referring to this line:           $new_combinations[] = $combination .' - '. $flav;

Comment: Did you remove this line `$ice_all = implode(', ',$ice_all);` and call `icecream()` function like this, `$output = icecream($ice_all, 2);` ?

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul works like a charm, great thankyou

Comment: I just wonder how duplicates can be removed. 'Vanilla - Strawberry', 'Strawberry- Vanilla' >>> remove one of them

Comment: @ceyrslan Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function to remove the duplicate values from the array.